# Capacitors between multiple positive power rails in cpu power system

Tags: power-supply, power, decoupling-capacitor, ram

Many years ago, when I was working in samsung aftermarket supply chain with set top box repairs I had  access to basic schematic of one of stb. In a power supply part for powering RAM there were a few rails - 1.0V, 1.5V, 2.2V, 3.3V etc. Normal part of this schematic have decouplig capacitors between power rails and power supply ground.

A bit unusual part was decoupling capacitors between positive supply rail, for example between 1.0V and 1.5V - here were a lot of capacitors with value about 10-1000nF, i suppose NP0 or C0G.

Why? What is the role of these capacitors? Did it idea have own name like as snubber or something?

I tried to google it but I always find basic info about decoupling capacitors or anyway - basics info.

Comment: Without seeing the circuit diagram and the physical layout of  the device this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Currents flow in loops. For (supply) current spikes it is good practice to keep these loops as small as possible. Perhaps circuits were used that draw current spikes between the supply rails instead between a supply rail and ground. Then the decoupling caps would need to be connected between those supply rails.

Comment: Alotta EE's really don't understand how decoupling actually works... Those caps may be some green engineers misapplication of capacitors.   Wouldn't suprise me one bit.   Dropping them in the schematic would be easy and they're cheap components.   They tested the boards, they worked,why go back and pick half-penny parts off and retest????   Alotta work there testing all the permutations, easier to just leave them in.